# Python: how to merge two different netCdf filles with different spatial resolution?

Tags: python, netcdf, gdal, geotiff

Is it possible to merge two netCDF files with different spatial resolution?

I have two datasets.

The first one is the [ESA Land Cover dataset](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php) with a spatial resoltion of `300m` as netCDF.

The first one is the population living in Italy with a spatial resolution of `100m` from [WorldPop](https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=26919) as a `geoTIFF` that I convert as `netCDF`.

This is what I am doing

```
## convert GeoTiff to netCDF
from osgeo import gdal
fin = ita_ppp_2000.tif'
fout = 'ita_ppp_2000.nc'
ds = gdal.Translate(fout, fin, format='NetCDF')
```

I download the ESA CCI data

```
year = 2000
import cdsapi
c.retrieve(
    'satellite-land-cover',
    {
        'variable': 'all',
        'format': 'zip',
        'version': 'v2.1.1',
        'year': str(y),
    },
    'download_%d.zip'%y) ## we need to unzip it

fn = 'ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-%d-v2.0.7cds.nc'%year## Global 300m resolution
```

I get the data for Italy

```
def clipEsa(fn,x0,x1,y0,y1):
    dnc = xr.open_dataset(fn)
    lat = dnc.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = dnc.variables['lon'][:]

    # All indices in bounding box:
    where_j = np.where((lon >= x0) & (lon <= x1))[0]
    where_i = np.where((lat >= y0) & (lat <= y1))[0]

    # Start and end+1 indices in each dimension:
    i0 = where_i[0]
    i1 = where_i[-1]+1

    j0 = where_j[0]
    j1 = where_j[-1]+1

    longitude = dnc["lccs_class"]["lon"].values[j0:j1]
    latitude = dnc["lccs_class"]["lat"].values[i0:i1]
    
    time = dnc['lccs_class']['time'][0]
    return dnc.sel(time=time, lon=longitude, lat=latitude) 

  wp = xr.open_dataset(fout)  ## Italian population with 100m resolution
  bb = [wp.lon[0].values, wp.lon[-1].values, wp.lat[0].values, wp.lat[-1].values] ## bounding box
  esaItaly = clipEsa(fn,bb[0],bb[1],bb[2],bb[3])  ## ESA CCI clipped for Italy
```

New I would like to have both the datasets at the spatial resolution of `300m`. In particular I would like to resample with a sum the `wp` dataset from `100m` to `300m` in the same pixels of `esaItaly`

This is what I tried

```
wp_inter = wp.interp(lat=esaItaly["lat"], lon=esaItaly["lon"])
```

but the total amount of population is much lower.

```
sum(wp_inter['Band1'].values[wp_inter['Band1'].values>0])
5038174.5   ## population interpolated

sum(wp.Band1.values[wp.Band1.values>0])
56780870.0   ## original population
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but probably the easiest one is by `gdalbuildvrt`.

Use `gdalbuildvrt` - either from the command-line either from the Python library - and build a `VRT` dataset. Make sure the highest resolution files are listed towards the end - if there is overlapping the final dataset wins.

Remember to use `[-resolution {highest|lowest|average|user}]` option.

Once you have a composite Dataset, use `gdal_translate` - CLI or Python - to consolidate it to a single monolithic Dataset in your preferred format.

Don't try to implement this yourself - it is more complicated than it might seem.